# Autoload a view Resolver in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, autoload

I'm using a view resolver to override `find_templates` method in `lib/resolvers/activities_resolver.rb`.

```
class ActivitiesResolver < ::ActionView::FileSystemResolver
 def initialize
   super('app/views')
 end

 def find_templates(name, prefix, partial, details)
   super(name, 'activities', partial, details)
 end
end
```

I'm using it in a controller`app/controllers/admin/activities_controller.rb`

```
class Admin::ActivitiesController < Admin::BaseController
  layout 'admin/usability_tests', only: :index
  append_view_path ActivitiesResolver.new

  def index
    @test = UsabilityTest.find(params[:usability_test_id])
    @activities = @test.activities
  end
end
```

In order to autoload this resolver, I added in `config/application.rb` :

`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/resolvers)`

This works perfectly, but I'd like to autoload all `/lib` subdirectories instead of having to specify them manually.

I'd like to write in `config/application.rb` :

`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/**/)`

but I cannot figure out how to make it works.

I red that I had to name the resolver

`class Resolvers::ActivitiesResolver < ::ActionView::FileSystemResolver`

but this returns me an `uninitialized constant` when I want to initialize it in controller.

Any help ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Adding
`config.autoload_paths << File.join(config.root, 'lib')`
instead of
`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/**/)` in `application.rb`
solved my problem :)